# React how to add lot new records and delete

Tags: reactjs

I just started to study the react, I need to add a few new records (in this case 3) to the table and then delete the whole line, but it turns out to be able to add data from only one field

one component is empty, then it is displayed with a get answer and then I want to do the same with my data and delete them

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            dataItems: []
        }
    }
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('example-tech.com')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({data: responseJson});
        })
}

addItem(value) {
    let newListItems = this.state.dataItems.slice();
    newListItems.push(value);

    this.setState({
        dataItems : newListItems
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <text />
            {/*fromGet*/}
            {this.state.data.map( function (record, index) {
                return(
                    <div className='form__row' key={index}>
                        <Hello
                            firstname={record.data.firstname}
                            lastname={record.data.lastname}
                            telegram={record.data.telegram}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
 {/*myNewRecords*/}
            {this.state.dataItems.map(function (item ,index) {
                return (
                    <Hello key={index} firstname={item} />
                );
            })}

            <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    )
}
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className='form__row'>
            <p className='form__input' > firstname: {this.props.firstname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> lastname: {this.props.lastname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> telegram: {this.props.telegram} </p>
            <button> Delete </button>
        </div>;
    }
}

class AddItem extends React.Component{
    handleClick(){
        this.props.addItem(this.item.value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='form__row'>
                <div>
                    <label >firstname</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item => this.item=item} />
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> Add new records</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue you are facing?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I missed something, and I can not add values to the table from three fields, it is always added from only one field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have implemented the **delete** functionality:

Checkout the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/25420/

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            dataItems: []
        }
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('example-tech.com')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({data: responseJson});
        })
}

deleteItem(index) {

  let array = this.state.dataItems;
  array.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({dataItems: array });
  console.log("coming here")
}

addItem(value) {
    let newListItems = this.state.dataItems.slice();
    newListItems.push(value);

    this.setState({
        dataItems : newListItems
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <text />
            {/*fromGet*/}
            {this.state.data.map( function (record, index) {
                return(
                    <div className='form__row' key={index}>
                        <Hello
                            firstname={record.data.firstname}
                            lastname={record.data.lastname}
                            telegram={record.data.telegram}
                            deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, index)} 
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
 {/*myNewRecords*/}
            {this.state.dataItems.map(function (item ,index) {
                return (
                    <Hello deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, index)}  key={index} firstname={item} />
                );
            }, this)}

            <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    )
}
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  handleOnClick() {
    this.props.deleteItem(this.props.key);
  }

    render() {
        return <div className='form__row'>
            <p className='form__input' > firstname: {this.props.firstname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> lastname: {this.props.lastname} </p>
            <p className='form__input'> telegram: {this.props.telegram} </p>
            <button onClick={this.props.deleteItem}> Delete </button>
        </div>;
    }
}

class AddItem extends React.Component{
    handleClick(){
        this.props.addItem(this.item.value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='form__row'>
                <div>
                    <label >firstname</label>
                    <input className='form__input'  type="text" ref={item => this.item=item} />
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> Add new records</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```